# How to set the starting page of appendix?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I want to know what is the logic inside the

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}
```

I want to set the starting page of appendix with X (in Roman, so 10 in arabic number), So in ToC it should look like

```
 Contents
 List of Figures.............i
 Chapter 1 ..................1
 Appendix ...................x
  Appendix A.................x
  Appendix B.................xi
```

. I have tried with

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10}
```

but it still comes out with i(so 1 in arabic number). And why rename for Appendix is not working? I don´t want

```
A Appendix
```

How to fix this? (in order to provide MWE, I have eliminate chapter 2, etc.)

Thank you

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=authortitle-comp,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}   
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}   
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10} 
\appendix \chapter{Appendix}
\section{Appendix A}
\section{Appendix B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `secnumdepth` counter has nothing to do with page numbering.  the `page` counter is what controls that.  so if you `\setcounter{page}{10}` you should get what you want, at least on the actual pages.  it might also be necessary to make the adjustment to roman also in the `.toc` file.

Comment: Hi , thank you for your reply, but how can I make the adjustment to roman in .toc file? @barbarabeeton

Comment: have to look that up, which may take some time.  basically, you need to insert a command into the `toc` file using `\addtocontents{toc}{<command>}`, but i'm not sure what the command is, and will have to dig it up.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't compile without errors; there's an option clash with the `appendix` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want three things:

- Make the word "Appendix" something else in the TOC.
- Start your page numbering at ten when you begin appendices.
- Have you page numbering romanettes rather than Arabic numerals for the appendices.

These can all be accomplished pretty easily.  But `\secnumdepth` isn't the way; that just refers to how many nested levels of sectioning are numbered.

The page numbering is easiest.  You've already seen how to change the numbering to romanettes; `\pagenumbering{roman}`.  To start at page ten, issue immediately afterwards `\setcounter{page}{10}`.  However, the `book` class does not allow first-level sections to begin on even-numbered (that is, left) pages, so if you really want it to be page ten, you'll have to add `openany` to the options to the `book` class.

For changing the name of the appendix, you load `appendix` twice with different options, so it causes an error.  Removing the first, you can do the following:

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{SomeName}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{SomeName}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{SomeName}
```

This should change the word "Appendix" to "SomeName" wherever it's generated by LaTeX.  (Remember that you've actually named your appendix and subsections thereof "Appendix", so it will remain there.)

So a minimal example accomplishing what you want might look like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{SomeName}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{SomeName}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{SomeName}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}   
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}   
\setcounter{page}{10}
\appendix \chapter{Appendix}
\section{Appendix A}
\section{Appendix B}
\end{document}
```

This should yield the following:

[image: First Page Spread]

[image: Last Page]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to the answer from @dgoodmaniii. I have modified the script, now it looks ok!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=authortitle-comp,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}   
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}   
\setcounter{page}{10}
\begin{appendices}
 \chapter{Appendix A}
\chapter{Appendix B}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```